# What is the proper index type for varbinary for mysql innodb db?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

im currently running the following query which is causing my db to jam when a multiple of these queries hit my db:

```
select * from ip_lookup where addr_type = 'ipv4' and ip_start <= '<9d>)Ü<86>' order by ip_start desc limit 1;

# Time: 200102  8:25:19
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 593.831791  Lock_time: 0.000090 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 3697391
```

ip_start is varbinary, addr_type is enum

what would be the most performant based index for these fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a normal B-tree index for enum and varbinary columns.

```
ALTER TABLE ip_lookup ADD INDEX (addr_type, ip_start)
```

The order of columns is important. First name columns you use in equality conditions (like `addr_type = ?`), then you can name *ONE* column you use in an inequality condition (`ip_start <= ?`) or in an `ORDER BY`.